# NServiceBus - I want AsA_Server config, but not participate in MSDTC transaction

Tags: nservicebus, msdtc

I have a service in which I don't want to messages to purged from its input queue when the service starts up and I don't want it to participate in an MSDTC transaction.  I'm configuring it's endpoint to run AsA_Server, but I can't see any way to disable starting an MSDTC transaction.  I'm using the NServiceBus.Host.exe.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsA_Server is just a shortcut for a bunch of options in a longer Configure.With() block.

Remove the AsA_Server interface, and then make sure the following is in your fluent configuration:

```
.MsmqTransport()
    .IsTransactional(false)
    .PurgeOnStartup(false)
```

Comment: I have it so it's not purging and not starting a transaction.  However, I'm testing how it handles exceptions, and the message is not being put into the error queue and only being execute once.  If I run AsA_Server, it puts the message into the error queue.

Comment: It puts the message in the error queue because it's transactional. If you disable transactions, it won't send messages to error queue.